# How to abort processing a request in NodeJS http server

Tags: node.js

I have your standard callback-hell `http` server like (simplified):

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    doSomething(() => {
        doMoreSomethings(() => {
            if (!isIt())
                // explode A

            if (!isItReally())
                // explode B

            req.on('data', (c) => {
                if (bad(c))
                  // explode C
            });

            req.on('end', () => {
                // explode D
            });
        });
    });
};
```

The only way I know of to end the request is `res.end()`, which is asynchronous, so stuff after you call that will run (as far as I can tell). Is there a way to do a pseudo-`process.exit` mid-flight and abort processing the request, so I don't waste time on other stuff? For example how can I stop at the above `// explode` lines and not process anything else? `throw` doesn't leap over scope boundaries. Basically, I think, I want to `return` or break out of the `createServer` callback from within a nested callback. Is the only way to do this to be able to have code with a single path and just not have more than one statement at each step? Like, horizontal coding, instead of vertical KLOCs.

I'm a Node noob obviously.

**Edit:** Maybe another way to ask the question is: Is it possible to abort at the `// explode C` line, not read any more data, not process the `end` event, and not process any more lines in the `doMoreSomethings` callback (if there were any)? I'm guessing the latter isn't possible, because as far as I know, `doMoreSomethings` runs to completion, including attaching the data and end event handlers, and only then will the next event in the queue (probably a data event) get processed, at which point `doMoreSomethings` is done. But I am probably missing something. Does this code just zip through, call `isIt` and `isItReally`, assign the event handlers, hop out of all the callbacks, the `createServer` callback finishes, and *then* all the extra stuff (data/end/etc.) runs from the event queue?

Comment: We would need to see real, actual working code, not the pseudo code you have here.  Aborting asynchronous operations is not a generic topic, but is specific to the exact operation.  Some can be aborted, some cannot.  There is no generic answer.  This can only be answered in the exact context of your real code.  If you have a sequence of operations, you may want to use promises so you can reject the promise and that will be communicated back to higher levels that can then act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will use a `return` statement. When you call `return` any code below it will not get executed. Although, if your functions `isIt()` or `isItReally()` are asynchronous functions then you will be running into trouble as those are used in a synchronous fashion.